# Pass PIC N(n) in safearray to COM object

Tags: c#, .net, com, cobol

I am creating this safearray in MicroFocus Cobol (for pass to COM object):

```
           move VT-BSTR to w-vartype
           move 1 to w-dimension
           compute w-y = a-x * 2
           move w-y to cElements of w-saBound(1)
           move 0 to llBound of w-saBound(1)
           invoke OLESafeArray "new"
            using by value w-vartype w-dimension
            by reference w-saBound(1)
            returning w-accArray
           end-invoke
           move a-x to cElements of w-saBound(1)
           invoke OLESafeArray "new"
            using by value w-vartype w-dimension
            by reference w-saBound(1)
            returning w-modArray
           end-invoke

           initialize w-x
           perform varying w-Index from 0 by 1 until w-Index >= w-y
             add 1 to w-x
             move n'aaa' to acc-bank-acc-num
             invoke w-accArray "putString"
              using by reference w-Index
                    by value 68
                    by reference w-acc-num(w-x)
              returning w-hresult
             end-invoke
             add 1 to w-Index
             invoke w-accArray "putString"
              using by reference w-Index
                    by value 68
                    by reference w-acc-result(w-x)
              returning w-hresult
             end-invoke
           end-perform

           perform varying w-Index from 0 by 1 until w-Index >= a-x
             invoke w-modArray "putString"
              using by reference w-Index
                    by value 4
                    by reference w-acc-mod(w-Index + 1)
              returning w-hresult
             end-invoke
           end-perform
```

When I am passing `PIC X(n)` variables (in sample `w-acc-num`, `w-acc-result`, etc.) everything is OK. But I need to process Unicode strings, so data type must be `PIC N(n)`. And then result in COM object (.NET C#) is bad, for example like this:

- I am sending: "1072907036"
- But in COM object I receive: "1\00\07\02\09\00\07\00\03\06\0"

I suppose, that problem is in type `VT_BSTR`, should I use `VT_VARIANT` instead? And if it so, how to properly use safearray of `VT_VARIANT`s? And I also returning this array back to COBOL.

Comment: Are you sending strings of binary data?  I thought COBOL only dealt with strings.  You com object looks like binary data.

Answer (score 1):

VT_BSTR is a Unicode string. So I would expect the methods you call on the safe array to convert the pic x(..) to a Unicode BSTR. It will just take the PIC N Buffer and convert it.

If you have these chars as sbcs (single byte charset) then it should go across as a string and be converted to BSTR on the way.

If using N" " national literals then make sure you use NSYMBOL"NATIONAL" directive or the system could interpret as a DBCS Literal.

Comment: Please is there any list of methods which could be called upon safearray? I must admint, that I don't understand your answer. If VT_BSTR is Unicode string, and I pass Unicode string as parameter, so it should be correct at the end, or not?

Comment: In Net Express v5.1 help navigate as follows from contents: Programming ---- Object-Oriented Programming ---- OO Class Libraries --- OO COBOL Class Library Reference ---- OLE Automation Class Library

Comment: putstring accepts PIC X(...) so is expecting sbcs and it converts to Unicode. Really need both sides to see where is could be going wrong. If its a byte array you want to pass rather than a string then a safearray of VT_UI1 would likely be better.

Comment: Ok, thanks for Help topic, I will try to get thru it. In my case on the other side, in C#, I put data to string[] array